# How to make a Slideshow that is both clickable and automatic?

Tags: slideshow

I would like to make a slideshow that rotates between images automatically and can also be activated by clicking.Examples of what I want to achieve can be found on Runescape.com,mmohut.com,and Yankees.com,please give me an html/css/javascript code to do this.THANK YOU :D

Answer (score 0):

Here it says how to make a slidshow like you said
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/show.shtml
if you want it to start on click, use `onclick="myFunction()` and put the code for the slideshow (the one in the body) into a function like this. Assign `onclick` to whatever you want clicked to start slideshow.

```
<script>
function functionname()
{
the code goes in here (not the <script> tags
}
</script>
```